# Vagrant - SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status

Tags: vagrant, ansible, ubuntu-14.04

I'm getting this error running for the first time `vagrant up`. Can't figure out what's wrong when executing the task: "TASK [server : Install Extra Packages]". 
Throws the error:

**The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant
assumes that this means the command failed. The output for this command
should be in the log above. Please read the output to determine what
went wrong.**

Below the log:

```
==> default: stdin: is not a tty
==> default: Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease
==> default: Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease [65.9 kB]
==> default: Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease [65.9 kB]
==> default: Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Sources [120 kB]
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg
==> default: Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Sources [384 kB]
==> default: Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Sources [45.8 kB]
==> default: Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main amd64 Packages [547 kB]
==> default: Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Sources [5,888 B]
==> default: Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages [144 kB]
==> default: Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Sources [169 kB]
==> default: Get:10 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-en [301 kB]
==> default: Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Sources [7,522 B]
==> default: Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages [918 kB]
==> default: Get:13 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en [85.0 kB]
==> default: Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [16.4 kB]
==> default: Get:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages [388 kB]
==> default: Get:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [14.0 kB]
==> default: Get:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en [445 kB]
==> default: Get:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-en [7,340 B]
==> default: Get:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en [3,842 B]
==> default: Get:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-en [205 kB]
==> default: Get:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Sources [9,632 B]
==> default: Get:22 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Sources [28 B]
==> default: Get:23 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Sources [35.2 kB]
==> default: Get:24 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Sources [1,898 B]
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main amd64 Packages
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted amd64 Packages
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe amd64 Packages
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Translation-en
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Translation-en
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Translation-en
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Translation-en
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release
==> default: Get:25 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources [1,064 kB]
==> default: Get:26 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Sources [5,433 B]
==> default: Get:27 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Sources [6,399 kB]
==> default: Get:28 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Sources [174 kB]
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted amd64 Packages
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe amd64 Packages
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en
==> default: Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_US
==> default: Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en_US
==> default: Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en_US
==> default: Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en_US
==> default: Fetched 11.6 MB in 10s (1,147 kB/s)
==> default: Reading package lists...
==> default: Reading package lists...
==> default: Building dependency tree...
==> default: Reading state information...
==> default: software-properties-common is already the newest version.
==> default: 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
==> default: gpg: 
==> default: keyring `/tmp/tmp5w8ex696/secring.gpg' created
==> default: gpg: 
==> default: keyring `/tmp/tmp5w8ex696/pubring.gpg' created
==> default: gpg: 
==> default: requesting key 7BB9C367 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
==> default: gpg: 
==> default: /tmp/tmp5w8ex696/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
==> default: gpg: 
==> default: key 7BB9C367: public key "Launchpad PPA for Ansible, Inc." imported
==> default: gpg: 
==> default: Total number processed: 1
==> default: gpg: 
==> default:               imported: 1
==> default:   (RSA: 1)
==> default: OK
==> default: Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease
==> default: Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease
==> default: Get:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease [16.0 kB]
==> default: Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Sources
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease
==> default: Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Sources
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease
==> default: Get:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages [525 B]
==> default: Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg
==> default: Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages
==> default: Get:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en [322 B]
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Sources
==> default: Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-en
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Sources
==> default: Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Sources
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Sources
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-en
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-en
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Sources
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Sources
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Sources
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Sources
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main amd64 Packages
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted amd64 Packages
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe amd64 Packages
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Translation-en
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Translation-en
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Translation-en
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Translation-en
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Sources
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Sources
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Sources
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted amd64 Packages
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe amd64 Packages
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en
==> default: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en
==> default: Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_US
==> default: Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en_US
==> default: Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en_US
==> default: Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en_US
==> default: Fetched 16.8 kB in 4s (3,720 B/s)
==> default: Reading package lists...
==> default: Reading package lists...
==> default: Building dependency tree...
==> default: Reading state information...
==> default: The following extra packages will be installed:
==> default:   python-jinja2 python-markupsafe python-paramiko python-setuptools sshpass
==> default: Suggested packages:
==> default:   python-jinja2-doc
==> default: The following NEW packages will be installed:
==> default:   ansible python-jinja2 python-markupsafe python-paramiko python-setuptools
==> default:   sshpass
==> default: 0 upgraded, 6 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
==> default: Need to get 2,129 kB of archives.
==> default: After this operation, 15.0 MB of additional disk space will be used.
==> default: Get:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ansible/ansible/ubuntu/ trusty/main ansible all 2.2.0.0-1ppa~trusty [1,608 kB]
==> default: Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main python-markupsafe amd64 0.18-1build2 [14.3 kB]
==> default: Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main python-jinja2 all 2.7.2-2 [161 kB]
==> default: Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main python-paramiko all 1.10.1-1git1build1 [106 kB]
==> default: Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main python-setuptools all 3.3-1ubuntu2 [230 kB]
==> default: Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe sshpass amd64 1.05-1 [10.5 kB]
==> default: dpkg-preconfigure: unable to re-open stdin: No such file or directory
==> default: Fetched 2,129 kB in 1s (2,109 kB/s)
==> default: Selecting previously unselected package python-markupsafe.
==> default: (Reading database ... 63004 files and directories currently installed.)
==> default: Preparing to unpack .../python-markupsafe_0.18-1build2_amd64.deb ...
==> default: Unpacking python-markupsafe (0.18-1build2) ...
==> default: Selecting previously unselected package python-jinja2.
==> default: Preparing to unpack .../python-jinja2_2.7.2-2_all.deb ...
==> default: Unpacking python-jinja2 (2.7.2-2) ...
==> default: Selecting previously unselected package python-paramiko.
==> default: Preparing to unpack .../python-paramiko_1.10.1-1git1build1_all.deb ...
==> default: Unpacking python-paramiko (1.10.1-1git1build1) ...
==> default: Selecting previously unselected package python-setuptools.
==> default: Preparing to unpack .../python-setuptools_3.3-1ubuntu2_all.deb ...
==> default: Unpacking python-setuptools (3.3-1ubuntu2) ...
==> default: Selecting previously unselected package sshpass.
==> default: Preparing to unpack .../sshpass_1.05-1_amd64.deb ...
==> default: Unpacking sshpass (1.05-1) ...
==> default: Selecting previously unselected package ansible.
==> default: Preparing to unpack .../ansible_2.2.0.0-1ppa~trusty_all.deb ...
==> default: Unpacking ansible (2.2.0.0-1ppa~trusty) ...
==> default: Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
==> default: Setting up python-markupsafe (0.18-1build2) ...
==> default: Setting up python-jinja2 (2.7.2-2) ...
==> default: Setting up python-paramiko (1.10.1-1git1build1) ...
==> default: Setting up python-setuptools (3.3-1ubuntu2) ...
==> default: Setting up sshpass (1.05-1) ...
==> default: Setting up ansible (2.2.0.0-1ppa~trusty) ...
==> default: [DEPRECATION WARNING]: Instead of sudo/sudo_user, use become/become_user and 
==> default: make sure become_method is 'sudo' (default).
==> default: This feature will be removed in a 
==> default: future release. Deprecation warnings can be disabled by setting 
==> default: deprecation_warnings=False in ansible.cfg.
==> default: 
==> default: PLAY [all] *********************************************************************
==> default: 
==> default: TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
==> default: ok: [192.168.10.15]
==> default: 
==> default: TASK [server : Update apt] *****************************************************
==> default: changed: [192.168.10.15]
==> default: 
==> default: TASK [server : Install System Packages] ****************************************
==> default: changed: [192.168.10.15] => (item=[u'curl', u'wget', u'python-software-properties'])
==> default: 
==> default: TASK [server : Install Extra Packages] *****************************************
==> default: failed: [192.168.10.15] (item=[u'server.packages']) => {"failed": true, "item": ["server.packages"], "msg": "No package matching 'server.packages' is available"}
==> default:    to retry, use: --limit @/vagrant/ansible/playbook.retry
==> default: 
==> default: PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
==> default: 192.168.10.15              : ok=3    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=1   
The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant
assumes that this means the command failed. The output for this command
should be in the log above. Please read the output to determine what
went wrong.
```

main.yml were appears "server.packages"

```
- name: Install Extra Packages
  sudo: yes
  apt: pkg={{ item }} state=latest
  with_items: server.packages
  when: server.packages is defined
```

The virtual machine comes from a configuraiton built in Phansible.com

Answer (score 3):

The Vagrant message at the end just reports that the session ended with a non-zero return code.  The cause for that return code is:

```
==> default: failed: [192.168.10.15] (item=[u'server.packages']) => {"failed": true, "item": ["server.packages"], "msg": "No package matching 'server.packages' is available"}
==> default:    to retry, use: --limit @/vagrant/ansible/playbook.retry
```

My guess would be that you meant to expand server.packages from a variable.  I.e.

```
with_items: '{{server.packages}}'
```

instead of

```
with_items: server.packages
```

or

```
with_items:
- server.packages
```

See the [Ansible Porting Guide, Deprecated section](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/porting_guide_2.0.html#deprecated)

Comment: the only places were appears the "server.packages" is main.yml and looks like this: - name: Install Extra Packages
  sudo: yes
  apt: pkg={{ item }} state=latest
  with_items: server.packages
  when: server.packages is defined

Comment: Without more info about the role and playbook, I can't surmise further.  Note, though, that more recent ansible versions warn that with_items does not support bare variables, and that they should be expanded via templating (as I lay out in my answer).  If the role is old, you may need to make this change to support your installed version of ansible .

Comment: See the "Deprecated" section at [Ansible Porting Guide](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/porting_guide_2.0.html)